# Maven release process

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I am having a problem with the Maven release process. I have created the compile phase of my process in such a way that you can compile the same version or a higher version, but you compiling a pervious version will error. (This is required as objects are being pushed into the database during the compile stage and I don't want these to regress to previous versions.)

I have a project and in the pom file it is specified that it is version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

I run maven release:prepare, using all the default settings and it works fine giving me a new pom file with the version 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT

I then run maven release:perform, and at this stage it hits an issue. 
It seems that it compiles version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT after it has already compiled version 0.0.1. Since 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT comes before 0.0.1 I get an error.

My question is why is the release plugin compiling 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT after it has already compiled 0.0.1. Also at this time the pom.xml has version 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.

Can anyone explain/point to documentation showing this process and if possible tell me how I can prevent this behavour.

Comment: This would only be the case if `release:prepare` somehow tagged a version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT instead of 0.0.1. Check your tag on your VCS, if it has the correct version. Also, `release:perform` relies on the `release.properties` file that `prepare` created, so make sure you don't modify / delete it between `prepare` and `perform`.

Comment: I checked the tag that is created in the git repo and it is " ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA-0.0.1", so that seems correct. Also I am not altering that properties file. I skimmed through it and it seems that all the info there is correct.

Comment: Check that the `<version>` in the POM in really 0.0.1 also in the tag. Can you post a sample of your logs when running `mvn release:perform`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My first answer was wrong)

My experiments have shown that the release plugin does do deployments in a strange order, version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT does get deployed AFTER 0.0.1

Since my deployment process requires the correct order it fails.
I have a workaround since my process won't do the deployment unless I have made any changes if I do a "mvn deploy" before I start the release process then the release process won't make any changes when it deploys "0.0.1" and I can work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-ran the process this morning carefully and it is now working without any errors. I don't understand what was going wrong.

My process is:
Initial:

```
pom version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (Same on gitlab and local clone)
tags: none
Latest Deployed to DB: Nothing deployed in DB
```

Run: mvn deploy command

```
pom version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (Same on gitlab and local clone)
tags: none
Latest Deployed to DB: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Run: mvn release:prepare

```
Input: release version - 0.0.1 (default accepted)
Input: SCM release tag or label - ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA-0.0.1 (default accepted)
Input: New development version - 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT (default accepted)
pom version: 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT (gitlab still shows 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
tags: ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA-0.0.1 (gitlab also shows this tag)
Latest Deployed to DB: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Release properties file has been created:

```
#release configuration
#Mon Sep 26 10:54:07 BST 2016
project.dev.metcarob.com.oracledb.sample.schema\:ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
scm.tagNameFormat=@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}
scm.tag=ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA-0.0.1
project.scm.metcarob.com.oracledb.sample.schema\:ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.connection=scm\:git\:ssh\://git@gitlab.com/rmetcalf9/ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.git
pushChanges=true
scm.url=scm\:git\:ssh\://git@gitlab.com/rmetcalf9/ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.git
preparationGoals=clean verify
project.rel.metcarob.com.oracledb.sample.schema\:ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA=0.0.1
remoteTagging=true
scm.commentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin] 
project.scm.metcarob.com.oracledb.sample.schema\:ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.tag=HEAD
project.scm.metcarob.com.oracledb.sample.schema\:ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.url=ssh\://git@gitlab.com\:rmetcalf9/ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA.git
exec.additionalArguments=-Dcmd.env\=dev -Dcmd.parent.sys\=soa
exec.snapshotReleasePluginAllowed=false
completedPhase=end-release
```

Run: mvn release:perform

```
Worked successfully this time!!!!
pom version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
tags: ICSchema_SAMPLE_UTIL_SCHEMA-0.0.1 (gitlab also shows this tag)
Latest Deployed to DB: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT*
```

*I have realized my Latest deployed to DB field is misleading as my process will only deploy to the DB if the hash of the PLSQL script has changed for each object so although it still shows 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT it still means that version 0.0.1 and 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT may have been deployed.

Not clearing the database may have been the cause of my issues.

Comment: You can update an existing answer, or delete this one if you think it is wrong...